# Find all usage for specific dll in other project

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I'm a member of a team with more than 20 developers, and each developer works on a separate module (something near 10 modules).
Each module has any DLL and use in other project i want when in the project search who use this class automatic search in the all of the project and show me result.

Comment: Do you want to find where a referenced dll is used within a given project, or do you want to find all the projects that a particular dll is referenced in?

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this, other than searching through the text in all the proj files for a particular reference.